# How to open "Picasa gallery" picture using Highslide

Tags: jquery, html, picasa, highslide

I tried to do this tutorial: http://www.webtoolkit.info/add-picasa-gallery-to-your-blog-or-website.html#more-418

I succeeded, but how I could open those pictures using Highslide (http://highslide.com)?
Now pictures are opening in the new window, and they are also not full size pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Markup each image according to the Highslide JS documentation:

```
<a href="images/full-image.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="images/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Highslide JS" title="Click to enlarge" height="120" width="107" /></a>
```

Modify `picasa.js` to include the above lines instead of what's appended in this line:

```
jQuery('#' + this.containerId).append('<div onClick="document.location.href=\''+this.itemsArray[x].media$group.media$content[0].url+'\'" class="picasaGalleryItem" style="cursor: pointer; width: ' + this.imageSize + 'px; height: ' + this.imageSize + 'px; background: url(' + this.itemsArray[x].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url + ') no-repeat center center; "></div>');
```

That gives you:

```
    jQuery('#' + this.containerId).append('<a href="' + this.itemsArray[x].media$group.media$content[0].url + '" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="' + this.itemsArray[x].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url + '" alt="Highslide JS" title="Click to enlarge" height="120" width="107" /></a>');
```

Comment: Does not work if I put this code. I don't see pictures at all after doing this.